# What field of health science deals with optimizing health for an average healthy person

Tags: preventative-medicine

Is there a field of health science dedicated to constructing strategies for the average person to optimize their health and longevity?

When I say average person, what I mean is that these should be strategies which are universal and not strategies for dealing with a specific disease/condition of some segment of the population. 
Examples for individual factors would be nutrition and exercise, which have similar recommendations for pretty much all people.

My question is if there is a field which is focused on optimizing health from a broad perspective, integrating nutrition, exercise, stress-management, and any other factors which contribute to overall health and longevity.

Thank you.

Comment: Many years ago, we called this "Wellness Medicine." I think today it's settled down into "Preventive Medicine". You're a lot less likely to come across quacks in preventive medicine than in wellness medicine. Maybe better answered on Health.SE?

Comment: It is a mix.  I would go with personal trainer / dietitian.

Comment: The problem here is that the scientific results obtained so far are not good enough. It's one thing to say that half an hour per day of moderate exercise is recommended and to back that up with scientific studies, but to say that X minutes per day at intensity Y is optimal requires a lot more knowledge (and X and Y will obviously vary from person to person and change as the person gets fitter) that simply doesn't exist at the moment.